# How is the module exported in Winston package?

Tags: javascript, node.js, winston

I am trying to read winston code base and I am having a problem understanding how this main module is exported? I have never seen this pattern, can someone explain to me how it works under the hood? isn't it supposed to be `const exports = winston` and not the other way around?

this is what I'm talking about:

```
/**
* Setup to expose.
* @type {Object}
*/
const winston = exports;
```

Comment: are you using winston for the logger implementation. usually in nodejs module.exports = loggger . then in the logger either it can be a function or an object we will create the config for the winston

Comment: @DILEEPTHOMAS I don't see how that's related to the question.

Comment: yes, but when you import winston the main entrance according to the package.json  settings is /bin/winston.js which only has the code I shared above as an export. so I wonder how it is working since its unlike the typical export method which you shared.

Comment: @DaveNewton yeah, i thought he is trying to implement the Logger

Comment: I actually am not using it yet, I just follow a routine of reading node packages every  morning for about an hour before I start classes. Today I started with winston.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`exports` is just an object. `winston` is a reference to the `exports` object.

It's the same as writing `exports.version = ...` etc.

Comment: oh ok now I get it, I forgot that exports is just an object and since it is an object it is copied by reference and not by value which means that adding properties to winston is actually just adding to exports since it holds the reference to it. That makes sense. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can see in the rest of the code that the writer is adding functions to this winston object, like so: `winston.Container = require('./winston/container'); winston.loggers = new winston.Container();`

So instead of exporting the module using the usual syntax of `module.exports`, the writer is actually working onto the exports object itself.

So basically 'winston' is just a reference to exports, which is a shorthand for module.exports.

So you can think of the entire module as written like this:
`module.exports.somePropertyName = 'someThing';`

Comment: Thanks Shilly, I forgot the exports is just an object that is copied by reference and not by value. Thanks!